# IR LEDs draw too little current

Tags: transistors, led, current, infrared, jetson

I am trying to set up a simple circuit using the GPIO pins of the [Jetson Xavier NX devkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-xavier-nx-devkit). I am using the 5V pin #2 to power a circuit with two IR LEDs connected in series. I've noticed that the LEDs are fairly dim and cannot draw more than about 100 mA. According to the documentation of the devkit, the 5V pin supports up to 1A load.

I am a newbie when it comes to circuits, and I'm struggling to understand how I could alter the circuit to let the LEDs draw more current.

On top of having the LEDs be powered by the Jetson, I'd also like to turn them on/off at will. To that end I'm trying to use a PNP darlington transistor where the base is connected to a GPIO pin. Since this pin is limited to 20uA, the idea is that the transformer will amplify the signal and let much more current flow. Yet again, the LEDs are quite dim.

I have attached the circuit diagram, and hope that someone can guide me in the right direction.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: What is your value of R1? Calculated on the resistance of 1 LED or two in series?

Comment: Do you have a current-limiting base resistor somewhere on "CTRL-JETSON-2"?

Comment: Your LEDs have a Vf of 1.5V each and your BC516 has a Vce(sat) of 1V, so that leaves 1V across R1. What value did you choose for R1? 10-ohms maybe ... ?

Comment: The datasheet for the BC516 darlington guarantees 1V saturation with a base current that is 1000 times less than the collector current. Then for a 100mA output current the minimum needed input current is 100uA but your input current is 5 times too low. You can use less input current if you allow the darlington nit to saturate using its hFE of 30,000 times but a high hFE darlington will burn out the LED and a low hFE darlington might produce dim LEDs.

Comment: Are you sure the Jetson GPIO pin can only deliver 20 uA?  That seem very low to me - I'd expect at least a couple of mA.

Answer (score 0):

It seems all your assumptions need to be checked.

> "Yet again, the LEDs are quite dim."

- These are infrared (IR) LEDs so very dim Red light is normal for 100 mA.
- Read this spec for [**SFH482**](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/588/osram_opto_semiconductor_sfh_480_sfh_482_lead_pb_f-2891524.pdf) , especially page 7 plots of current is 200 mA max for DC and 5% max at 1 Amp using 1 kHz minimum (\$10^3 \text{ mA @ }10^{-3} s\$).
- Then V vs I plot shows Vf= 2.4V @ 1 A  (\$10^0 A ~@~ V_F=2.4V\$), thus two LEDs will be almost 4.8V when pulsed for <=50 us.

Show by weblink and page # for your assumption for GPIO output current and voltage.

If you can control duty cycle to not burnout LED then a low side 1A switch is needed with LED normally to V+ supply with current limited by voltage drop divided by series R. Since two in series needs a 0.2 Ohm logic level switch from 5V, it may be easier with 2 in parallel from 3.3V.

I cannot assume you know how to design a logic pulse switch. But there are many examples on this site.

### Recommendation

Re-start  your question (edit) by describing what you are trying to perform with LED and link your datasheets and list all assumptions or specs.

[There are many ways to do this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=LED%20pulse%20driver)   but we must be sure what you really are trying to do.